# C++ attempting to populate BST failing with when reaching 164th object

Tags: c++, csv, binary-search-tree

I'm a CS college student attempting to make a project for fun. I'm attempting to organize a weapons list via reading a .csv file containing weapons and their attributes from Dark Souls 3. I'm currently using binary search tree methods that I worked through from a previous assignment. Currently, there are 189 weapons, but the addNode() function gets to 163 and then crashes. Weapon is a struct that holds 27 variables.

```
struct Weapon {
    int weaponID = -1; // unique identifier
    ...
};

...

void BinarySearchTree::Insert(Weapon weapon) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node(weapon);
    }
    else {
        addNode(root, weapon);
    }
}

void BinarySearchTree::addNode(Node* node, Weapon weapon) {
    if (node->weapon.weaponID > weapon.weaponID) {
        if (node->left == nullptr) {
            node->left = new Node(weapon);
        }
        else {
            this->addNode(node->left, weapon);
        }
    }
    else {
        if (node->right == nullptr) {
            node->right = new Node(weapon);
        }
        else {
            this->addNode(node->right, weapon);
        }
    }
}

void loadWeapons(string csvPath, BinarySearchTree* bst) {
    cout << "\n--- Loading file " << csvPath << " ---\n" << endl;

    vector<string> fileLines;
    ifstream weaponsFile;
    weaponsFile.open(csvPath);

    if (weaponsFile.is_open()) {
        while (weaponsFile.good()) {
            string line;
            getline(weaponsFile, line);
            if (line != "")
                fileLines.push_back(line);
        }
        weaponsFile.close();

        if (fileLines.size() == 0) {
            cout << "No data was found in " << csvPath << "." << endl;
        }

        cout << "File read successfully.\n" << endl;
    }

    if (fileLines.size() != 0) {
        cout << "Allocating data...\n" << endl;
        for (size_t i = 2; i < fileLines.size(); ++i) {
            Weapon weapon; // new weapon object
            string currLine = fileLines.at(i);
            vector<string> brokenStrings = splitString(currLine, ',');
            if (brokenStrings.size() == 0) {
                cout << "Incorrect file format." << endl;
                return;
            }
            
            weapon.weaponID = i - 1;
            weapon.weaponName = brokenStrings.at(0);
            if (brokenStrings.at(1) != "") {
                weapon.reqStr = brokenStrings.at(1);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(2) != "") {
                weapon.reqDex = brokenStrings.at(2);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(3) != "") {
                weapon.reqInt = brokenStrings.at(3);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(4) != "") {
                weapon.reqFth = brokenStrings.at(4);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(5) != "") {
                weapon.weight = brokenStrings.at(5);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(6) != "") {
                weapon.crit = brokenStrings.at(6);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(7) != "") {
                weapon.dmgPhys = brokenStrings.at(7);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(8) != "") {
                weapon.dmgMag = brokenStrings.at(8);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(9) != "") {
                weapon.dmgFire = brokenStrings.at(9);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(10) != "") {
                weapon.dmgLtn = brokenStrings.at(10);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(11) != "") {
                weapon.dmgDark = brokenStrings.at(11);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(12) != "") {
                weapon.auxBleed = brokenStrings.at(12);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(13) != "") {
                weapon.auxPoison = brokenStrings.at(13);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(14) != "") {
                weapon.auxFrost = brokenStrings.at(14);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(15) != "") {
                weapon.scaleStr = brokenStrings.at(15);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(16) != "") {
                weapon.scaleDex = brokenStrings.at(16);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(17) != "") {
                weapon.scaleInt = brokenStrings.at(17);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(18) != "") {
                weapon.scaleFth = brokenStrings.at(18);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(19) != "") {
                weapon.weaponType = brokenStrings.at(19);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(20) != "") {
                weapon.damageType = brokenStrings.at(20);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(21) != "") {
                weapon.weaponSkill = brokenStrings.at(21);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(22) != "") {
                weapon.spellBuff = brokenStrings.at(22);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(23) == "Y") {
                weapon.buffable = true;
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(24) != "") {
                weapon.upgradeMat = brokenStrings.at(24);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.at(25) != "") {
                weapon.AR = brokenStrings.at(25);
            }
            if (brokenStrings.size() == 27) {
                weapon.notes = brokenStrings.at(26);   
            }
            brokenStrings.clear();
            bst->Insert(weapon);
            displayWeapon(weapon);
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Weapon data has been stored successfully.\n" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open " << csvPath << ".\n" << endl;
    }
    fileLines.clear();
}
```

displayWeapon() is a function that prints the weapon and its attributes, which is working as intended. displayWeapon() function and subsequent cout << endl; is only implemented in for loop for testing purposes, which is how I figured the iteration is stopping at 163, as it will print all weapons and and their attributes up to and including weaponID 163 and then crash, (**edit**: error displayed is *Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF79DA7667E in DS3BuildTracker.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000005589C03FF8)* which is flagged at the following code block in new_scalar.cpp) where debugging flags the following:

```
_CRT_SECURITYCRITICAL_ATTRIBUTE
void* __CRTDECL operator new(size_t const size)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        if (void* const block = malloc(size))
        {
            return block;
        }

        if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
        {
            if (size == SIZE_MAX)
            {
                __scrt_throw_std_bad_array_new_length();
            }
            else
            {
                __scrt_throw_std_bad_alloc();
            }
        }

        // The new handler was successful; try to allocate again...
    }
}
```

I am still incredibly novice when it comes to this stuff, and am only working with the knowledge I have from the courses I've already completed, so I have no idea what I'm doing here to be honest and recognize that I'm likely implementing a large degree of inefficiency. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `std::stoi` will throw an exception if the string you give it cannot be parsed as an integer. What exact data are you using at the time when you determined that this function fails?

Comment: @paddy the weaponID parameter is currently a string and the data being stored in it is a number between 1 and 189, as there are 189 weapons(lines) in the .csv that's being read. I've confirmed that weaponID variable is holding the right info and adheres to the conditions in my first statement. addNode() is currently storing nodes in the tree in the (weaponID) order 1, 10, 100,  ...,11, 110, ..., 189, 2, 20, 21.. etc. whereas it should be 1, 2, 3, ..., 189

Comment: How exactly did you determine that `stoi` is at fault here? Does it correctly convert every value you've given it into an integer? What does "loading fails" actually mean, in terms of observable behavior? Does your program crash? What happens? The best way to debug a program is to assume that none of your code works, and you must therefore test everything that happens between the time you run the program up until the time you observe unexpected behavior. It would help if you [edit] your question to show the definition of `Weapon`, so some of your claims can be verified.

Comment: @paddy I've largely edited the question with more details and decided to forego the string to int conversion and declare weaponID as size_t rather than a string; this is working where it needs to, but I think I may be leaking memory as the program still fails at a certain point. Trying to find answers to similar problems seems to refer to rule of 3/5/0, but I'm having a hard time deciphering these rules when reading up on them as I have no prior experience with them.

Comment: Just two general hints, as there's no real chance to analyse your problem (you didn't tell, what the error says and where it occurs; your add-function looks OK, but there's not much context). As for the hints: (1) switch on (a lot) compiler warnings, and fix code with warnings. E.g. `size_t weaponID = -1;` should rightly raise a warning as `size_t` is unsigned. (2) Don't use `new` or `delete`! They are only still in the language so that legacy code can compile, they are not part of modern c++ . Learn about smart pointers (`shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `unique_pointer`).

Comment: @kaba Appreciate the feedback; I'm sorry for the lack of information, this is only my second time seeking help on here and struggle with determining what I need to be sharing in order to provide optimal context. I will edit the question and add the error details when I get back on my pc. I'll look into your hints as well, thank you.

Comment: @kaba error has been added as an edit to the original question post

Comment: The error is a stack overflow. That suggests you have unbounded recursion and you should look at your tree insertion as the primary suspect. Note that because your tree is unbalanced, then if all the weapons in the file are ordered numerically by weapon ID, then your tree insertion is going to act like a linked list. _i.e._ if you have 163 weapons specified in order, then you will make 163 recursive calls. This is still speculation, but you can examine the call stack in your debugger look down a few levels. Tree insertion does not need to be recursive. I suggest you rewrite it to use a loop.

Comment: @paddy Your suspicion of unbounded recursion matches my own. Per the coursework I'm referencing for this project, I've only learned how to populate a BST using recursion and am not sure how to implement a loop method rather than the current recursive one. I may switch the data structure from a BST to a Vector to make things easier for myself; I initially wanted to use the BST for its sorting properties, but I think I might forego it at this point in favor of a Vector, as the .csv already lists the weapons in the desired order. I appreciate your continued guidance, thank you.

Comment: As with all data structure work, _draw_ out your tree on paper if you want to figure out how to implement insertion in a loop. It sure would be simpler to use a vector though. If you want the results to be sorted, then sort it afterwards (using a good sort algorithm such as `std::sort`). Right now, your tree implementation will have the performance characteristics of bubble sort or insertion sort because the tree insertion is worst-case O(N). Therefore you have O(N^2) insertion complexity and O(N) search, nullifying most benefits of a BST. Why not use `std::map` if you want a proper BST?

Comment: @paddy As stated, my knowledge base is currently limited to what I've learned in school and `std::map` has not been covered. I will look into it, however. I'm trying to branch out of just learning through school to expand my knowledge, which inspired this project I'm working on. BST has better performance in certain applications, per what I've learned, and I figured working with this structure as opposed to a simpler one would provide better experience with less familiar data structures. Admittedly, deciphering new knowledge independently is rather challenging compared to school.